# Calculate m and n of function g(x) knowing it admits an local minimum in point (2;4)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Let $g(x) = 3x^2 + mx + n$
>
> I'm trying to solve this problem.
>
> - First, I calculate $g(2) = 4$, which implies $-8 = 2m + n$
> - After, I calculate the derivative of $g(x)$, which is $g'(x) = 6x + m$

The problem I'm facing right now is that I need the exact value of $g'(x)$ to get $m$.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quadratic with coefficient of $x^2$ +ve is upward opening parabola with minimum at vertex. 
$$Let \,\,y=ax^2+bx+c $$
Minimum exist at vertex whose coordinates are $(-\frac{b}{2a},-\frac{D}{4a})$
$$  $$
For given equation a=3 , b=m , c=n 
$$\therefore -\frac{m}{6}=2 \,\,and\,\,-(\frac{m^2-12n}{12})=4$$
$$\therefore m=-12 , n=16 $$

Answer (score 1):

We have $ g'(2)=0$. Can you proceed?

Comment: $ g'(2)=0$ because in x=2 there's the local minimum?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. But since $(2,4)$ is a local minimum of $g$, we must have $g'(2)=0$, so you can now complete the problem.

---

An alternative approach is from analytic geometry. Note that $g(x)$ is a parabola, so its minimum must be its vertex, which for a parabola $ax^2+bx+c$ always lies at $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$, which in your case yields $2 = -\frac{m}{6}$, which makes the problem equivalently trivial...

---

First one may be a little quicker, but the second one requires no calculus whatsoever.